# How can i execute a prepared SQL statement multiple times inside a FOR loop ?

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, prepared-statement

I want to insert multiple rows to my table using prepared statements, And for that matter i use loops to extract data from an Array and use it for y statement parameters,  Here's my code sample :

```
require_once("connect.php");
$data_array = Array();
$string = 'faycal,18,12,2016,podes|Arab,19,12,2016,kashi|faycal,20,12,2016,exec';
function create_array($input){
    $formated_array = explode('|', $input);
    $query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table (bill_name,bill_num,month,year,type) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        for ($i = 0;$i < count($formated_array);$i++){
            for($j = 0;$j < 5;$j++){
                $data_array[$i][$j] = explode(',', $formated_array[$i])[$j];
            }
            $query->bind_param($name, $num, $month, $year, $type);
            $name =  $data_array[$i][0];
            $num = (int)$data_array[$i][1];
            $month = (int)$data_array[$i][2];
            $year = (int)$data_array[$i][3];
            $type = $data_array[$i][4];

            $query->execute();
        }   
        echo "Records have been saved successfully";

}
create_array($string);
```

I've tested this function without executing the statement and tried to echo data_array, Everything worked perfectly So I'm assuming there's something wrong with my SQL statements which i can't figure out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SCOPE, Scope, scope** The `$con` variable is not visible inside the function by default. SO pass it into the function as a parameter.

```
function create_array($con, $input){
    $query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table
                                  (bill_name,bill_num,month,year,type) 
                            VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    // ... the rest of your function body ...
}

require_once("connect.php");
$string = 'faycal,18,12,2016,podes|Arab,19,12,2016,kashi|faycal,20,12,2016,exec';
create_array($con, $string);
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use a global declaration like `global $con;` in the function before the variable is referenced. Your solution would be better when extensibility is an issue, i.e. if there are multiple connections and you need to specify which. But the global approach leads to more concise and readable code when extensibility is not an issue (in my experience, many web applications only have one connection), because you only write the global declaration once, whereas you might have to pass that parameter many times.

Comment: @cazort Good lord! GLOBALS are never a solution, just the prelude to confusion and unexplainable errors

Comment: I've been using globals, mindfully and sparingly, for years in dozens of web applications, and have not once had a problem with them. Database connections in scripts with a single connection are one of the few times I ever use them. They are overused but that's a completely separate issue. This is one instance where, for many applications, they work fine and lead to more concise and readable code.